# How to avoid duplicating the schema of an API to serve both XML and JSON?

Tags: json, xml, rest, openapi

I'm  defining an API for a resource (document) that has a collection of tags. Each tag can be of any type, and each tag type defines a different set of properties.

The XSD for the document looks like this:

```
<complexType name="Document">
    <sequence>
        <element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element name="tags" type="TagsList" minOccurs="0"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="TagsList">
    <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <any processContents="lax" namespace="http://www.example.com/schema/tags"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

Thus, the XML looks like this:

```
<document>
  <description>the description</description>
  <tags>
    <tagA>
      <propA1>...</propA1>
      <propA2>...</propA2>
      ...
    </tagA>
    <tagB>
      <propB1>...</propB1>
      <propB2>...</propB2>
      ...
    </tagB>
    ...
  </tags>
</document>
```

This object is part of an API that accepts both xml and json. If I serialize the document in json without an adapter, the response looks like this:

```
{
  "document": {
    "description": "the description",
    "tags": [{
      "propA1": "...",
      "propA2": "..."
    }, {
      "propB1": "...",
      "propB2": "..."
    }]
  }
}
```

This is not OK as the type of the tag is dropped, and the consumer will not be able to map it to the proper tag type without guessing. Instead, I'm writing the following json response with an appropriate adapter:

```
{
  "document": {
    "description": "the description",
    "tags": {
      "tagA": {
        "propA1": "...",
        "propA2": "..."
      }, 
      "tagB": {
        "propB1": "...",
        "propB2": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm now facing an issue with the API definition: depending on the response type (xml or json), the schema is different:

- in XML, the tags is a List of tags
- in json, the tags is a map indexed with the tag type

Therefore, the API contains 2 components, namely DocumentXml and DocumentJson, for the same resource. Moreover, because the Document object is also part of other objects as an attribute, each of these objects must now be defined in both XML and json versions all the way up the components hierarchy, which leads to a complete duplicate model for just that tiny difference.

Is there another way to define the Document component so that it can be used for both json and XML?
Or is there a clean way to avoid this duplication?

The API is documented with openapi.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, automated conversions between XML and JSON (or vice versa) tend to produce unsatisfactory results. If you want an XML interface that looks like well-designed XML and a JSON interface that looks like well-designed JSON then you will probably have to design them and maintain them separately.